# In Cypress, how do I force a PDF file to download instead of opening in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, download, cypress

In a web application that I don't control, I need to test that the PDFs that are generated by pressing a button actually have the information that is required.

I managed to do this using pdf-parse and cy.task, but I can only apply it if I download the PDF file.

Using npx cypress open I have Chrome set to download the PDF instead of opening it in a new tab, and it works perfectly, but when I try running npx cypress run then it stops working, even if I choose Chrome as the browser.

In Protractor there is a setting that forces Chrome to download instead of opening PDFs, but I can't find a similar option in Cypress.

Could someone recommend me what to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find the solution to the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your backend to set the `Content-Disposition` (because opening in the browser is desired for a real user), but you still want your test to download the file, then you can intercept the request and set it in cypress as below

```
// describe block

beforeEach(() =>
  cy.intercept(/.*\.pdf$/, (req) => {
    const pdfName = req.url.split("/").at(-1);
    console.log("Downloading pdf instead of opening in browser", {
      url: req.url,
      pdfName,
    });

    req.continue((res) => {
      res.headers["Content-Disposition"] = `attachment; filename=${pdfName};`;
    });
  })
);

// test to click a PDF link and verify downloaded file
```